# Unable to access pip installed packages from anaconda jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

when i try to import tensorflow from jupyter notebooks. I'm facing a error `No module named 'tensorflow'` .
But i have installed tensorflow using pip command, and it available in this path `c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages`.
please tell me how to access packages installed via pip from jupyter notebooks?

Comment: Did you `pip install tensorflow` in some specific environment? In that case the env needs to be activated before you launch the jupyter notebook server.

Comment: Check if you are running the import in the environment you installed it in.

Comment: As an aside, why install tensorflow using pip?

Answer (score 1):

When you installed tensorflow you had a specific environment active and that is where tensorflow was installed. If you are using Anaconda and did not specify which environment to make active it installed it in the base environment. If you want to install tensorflow to a specific environment (lets call it tf) then start the anaconda prompt and enter the text conda activate tf. Then install tensorflow with pip in the same window. My recommendation is to install tensorflow with conda versus pip. conda installs tensorflow and also installs the cuda toolkit and the proper version of cuDNN. pip does not do that. If you install tensorflow with conda I believe it installs version 2.1, cuda toolkit version 10.1.243 and cuDNN version 7.6.5.